# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified and ORA-06413: Connection not open

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, oracle10g

i have installed windows 2008 operating system with 64 bit and oracle 10g database and visual studio 2015.

unable to connect with oracle database 10g.

and existing developed application which is developed with visual studio 2010 that is working on windows xp with oracle 10g database.

Please help me.

Comment: please guide me how to connect with database.

Comment: existing application make connection then error shows ORA-06413: Connection not open. and while make new connection using server explorer --->Data connection -->add new connection in test connection error message : ----------->ORA-12154: TNS: Could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Can you try the below

1. Include Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll in your solution.
2. In web.config, Under Configuration and connectionstrings, include the below

    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
          <dataSources>
            <dataSource alias="UATDB" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ORACLEDBIP)(PORT = PORT))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ORACLE)))"/>
        </dataSources>
        </version>
      </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>

        <connectionStrings>
        <add name="UATCONNECTIONSTRING" connectionString="Data Source=UATDB;User Id=username;Password=password;Min Pool Size=10; Connection Lifetime=300;Connection Timeout=300;Incr Pool Size=5;Decr Pool Size=2;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>  
      </connectionStrings>


3. Refer the dll in your application

    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess;

    using (OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(strOracleConn))
    {
        oraConn.Open();
        OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand();
        oraCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oraCommand.CommandText = "sp name";
        oraCommand.Connection = oraConn;
    }



Web.config file

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"/>
  </configSections>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="UATDB" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IP)(PORT = PORT))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ORACLE)))"/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="UATCONNECTIONSTRING" connectionString="Data Source=UATDB;User Id=user1;Password=pass12;Min Pool Size=10; Connection Lifetime=300;Connection Timeout=300;Incr Pool Size=5;Decr Pool Size=2;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
        <conversionPattern value="../Logs/RunningLog/WrapperRunningLog-" />
      </file>
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMddHH.lo\g" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppenderUpdateStatus" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
        <conversionPattern value="../Logs/UpdateStatusLog/StatusLog-" />
      </file>
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd.log" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
    </root>
    <logger name="RunningLog">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"   />
    </logger>
    <logger name="UpdateStatusLog">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppenderUpdateStatus" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"   />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'Provider' is an invalid connection string attribute

Comment: can you please tell which provider name.i am using below connection string.

Comment: <add name="DDTS" connectionString="Provider=ORAOLEDB;Data Source=datasource;User Id=userid;Password=password;Min Pool Size=10; Connection Lifetime=300;Connection Timeout=300;Incr Pool Size=5;Decr Pool Size=2;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>

Comment: Under configuration section use the below and refer the same in data source alias name in connection string element as mentioned above.
 <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="UATDB" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DBIP)(PORT = PORT))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)))"/>
       </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>

Comment: getting this error Unrecognized configuration section oracle.manageddataaccess.client.  my_app\web.config

Comment: Have amended my previous post to include the web.config. You can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </configSections>
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
            <dataSources>
                <dataSource alias="UATDB" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ipadd)(PORT = port))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcle)))"/>
            </dataSources>
        </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
<connectionStrings> 
        <add name="Audit" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=UATDB;User Id=userid;Password=password;Min Pool Size=10; Connection Lifetime=300;Connection Timeout=300;Incr Pool Size=5;Decr Pool Size=2;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
<system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
            <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: here is my web.config file.

Comment: while running error is shown ----------->ORA-12154: TNS: Could not resolve the connect identifier specified.